# How to search for extensions created by Microsoft

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How do I within the VS Code IDEA under the Extensions panel search the marketplace for Extensions that are created by Microsoft or any other specific author?

Please post an example of a search such as

> Find an Extension that handles UML that was created by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried `@publisher:microsoft` and it worked:

[image: Screenshot from VSCode showing extension search on '@publisher:microsoft']

Comment: This is great!  Where might I find a listing of these key terms to use for searching such as the '@publisher' ?

Comment: What about searching beyond the publisher? If I am looking for a publisher and a keyword? e.g. microsoft as the publisher and UML as the keyword.

Comment: @Elijah. I just made a guess and it worked. The key `@publisher` seems to be undocumented; it's not even in [this list](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a4ec86d265040c9abe00d937d3e7dfcd1119f546/src/vs/workbench/contrib/extensions/common/extensionQuery.ts#L16) in the code.

Comment: Yeah that makes zero sense that it works but is not in their code as a key term. thanks for the link much appreciated.

Comment: @Elijah. After some more testing I find that the @ sign isn't needed. It's enough with `publisher:microsoft`. This can also be used for [searching on the Marketplace web page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=publisher%3Amicrosoft&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

Comment: I was looking into the file link and the extensions. I tried this and it filtered down tothe publisher and the keyword in this particular test case 'sql'. '@ publisher:microsoft @ sort:name @ ext:SQL'